# How to use .net objects with Crystal Reports?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have to build a complicated report and I don't know exactly how. I have some columns and two subreports in different detail sections. I send to the subreports a parameter that represents the value of the current row for a certain column. My problem is that when I finish to send all the values of my column (the subreports parameters) to the subreports, I have to change the parameter that I send to the subreport into the value from another column, without sending same parameter twice.

I belive that I could create this report much more easy if I use .net objects but my problem is that I don't know how to design my report. I would like to use an IEnumerable collection as the data source for the report. Or perhaps there is a formula to do this.

Could you please explain me how to do that?

Comment: It's not answer, but I can't be quiet - Crystal Reports are the worst choice of reporting tool, you can do. I strongly recommend any other tool (both free and comercial) because any of them is much more better.

Comment: @TcK, that's a very strong opinion you have with no evidence.  Can you give any examples?  I use Crystal almost daily to make professional PDF reports and don't have alot of problems with it.

Comment: @PowerUser: Yes - it's very strong opinion. But this opinion originate from 7 years experience in reporting. The Crystal Reports are the worst in technology (i.e. dynamic creation reports at run-time and/or extension reports at runtime), are the worst in productivity for programers/designers. And "the best one" the price is bigger than other tools (with or without source code). I realy don't see any reason why should I spent more money for tool and more time for report-production in less comfort of designer and API.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how complicated your report is, but I don't think you need special objects just to get data into the subreport.

What if your subreport just pulled the data directly from the source instead of being passed from the main report? i.e. your single values are passed from the main report, but if you need to get an entire column, then you go straight to the source.

Example: Your report groups sales by customerID.  For each customer, there is a subreport.  In each of those subreports, you want to count the total number of customers for some reason.  So you pass the 1 customerID from the main report to the subreport.  To get the complete list of customerIDs in the subreport, you pull directly from your datasource.

Alternative Idea:
Can you just do the calculation in the main report and pass the result to the subreport?

Comment: No, I don't think I can pass a result to the subreport. The thing is that I have to pass the values of a column, then some values of another columns, without repeating these values. I have to take care of the order of passing these values to the subreports, because I need a specific order.

Comment: In that case, how about doing all your calculations externally? This way, you can use good old SQL to do all the heavy lifting. For example, Crystal could pull the final results from a query in an MS Access table which does all the hard work.